# PHP: while dont return all rows

Tags: php, while-loop, fetch

I m using PHP in order to create a file with MySql query. The query works fine and brings 100.000 recs but the "while" procedure using fetch_assoc o fetch_array fails at some point (always the same point).

I have removed all the php-code to write the file and left just the "while" part, but still fails.

My server dont report any error then i have no reason to think its a memory issue.  Any idea?

```html
 while ($row = cnxx_fetch_assoc($result))
   {  
 for($i = 1; $i <=count($arrTitulo); $i++)
          {    fwrite($fh,eregi_replace("[\n|\r|\n\r]", " ",$row[$arrTitulo[$i][1]]));
                 fwrite($fh, "\t");
                 }
 fwrite($fh, "\n");
   }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the count of $arrTitulo?

Comment: Try `echo` instead of `fwrite` to see if all the rows are being printed. Also, running `count` on every iteration of the loop is a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks Pyromonk, i will change the count, I already did what you suggest using echo and didnt works fine. At the end i got the same escenario: Just print 40% of the recs.

Comment: Why "fetch_assoc", but then use "[1]"??